# Custom libraries on Google AppEngine Python 3.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip, gdal

I'm trying to deploy a service on Google AppEngine Python 3.7 standard environment, which requires a set of libraries as dependencies. One of the dependencies (GDAL 2.2.2) cannot be deployed returning error message:

```
File upload done.
Updating service [pycloud-wms]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 04c3dcfd- 
230d-44ad-981a-8819a5f60130 status: FAILURE.
Error ID: 9E195939.
Error type: InternalError.
Error message: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-p30r4tj3/gdal/
error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1.
```

I'm wondering about the reason for this error and also if anyone knows a way of solving this problem on GAE.

NOTE: I know I can deploy my application using GAE Flexible environment using a container, but the price difference between both approaches is quite substantial.

Comment: Can u show your app.yaml file

Comment: Here are my [app.yaml](https://gist.github.com/prl900/71cdc6e30e9ad34f6d21f70ee5a3626f) and [requirements.txt](https://gist.github.com/prl900/53c99ed5d9b52bcb71666a3a285cefd6) files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [dependencies in the Google App Engine Python3.7 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies) are installed using the Python package manager `pip`.

To install a Python package in the GAE Standard Python3.7 runtime it needs to be offered as a pip-installable Python library.

The [GDAL package](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) is installable via `pip`, but it requires the `libgdal` and `gdal-devel` platform packages to be installed, which don't come in the base runtime for App Engine Standard Python3.7 runtime.

The solution is to use the GAE Flex environment and install these platform-level dependencies first.

Comment: This is not quite true. The `GDAL` package is installable via `pip`, but it requires the `libgdal` and `gdal-devel` platform packages to be installed, which don't come in the base runtime for App Engine's 3.7 runtime. The solution is to use Flex and install these platform-level dependencies first.

Comment: @DustinIngram Thank you for the point I was missing, I edited my answer.