# Google App Engine rtree Python Module Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine

Google App Engine, does not include libspatialindex, and hence I am unable to install rtree python module, even if it is in requirements.txt,

it gives following error, while deploying app. ( app works fine locally. ) How do I install specific lib in python standard google app engine environment ? or How do I request them to do so ?

```
Collecting rtree
  Downloading Rtree-0.9.4.tar.gz (62 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/python3.8/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-0tyv4fij
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import rtree
      File "/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .index import Rtree
      File "/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import core
      File "/tmp/pip-install-hl9513g_/rtree/rtree/core.py", line 143, in <module>
        rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
      File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 386, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
      File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 391, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    AttributeError: /opt/python3.8/bin/python3: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [flexible environment with custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) to utilize packages not preinstalled in standard environment.

To install libspatialindex, add this to the Dockerfile:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a custom runtime?  You can install many packages with just regular GAE flex.

Comment: Not all dependencies come with Python 3.7  runtime. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982288/12232507)